# Tips for Removing Fuzz from Peaches?

Tags: peaches

I like to use peaches with the skin on when possible, but I'm not a big fan of all that fuzz.

Does anyone have a fuzz-removal method that works particularly well? Currently, I just rub the peaches with a rough cloth. I didn't know if I was missing out on some other, great method.

Comment: Really? What's wrong with you? :)

Comment: A nice rinse with NAIR?  Just kidding....but...no, if you try it you're on your own...

Comment: In my defense, they're REALLY fuzzy. I don't mind normal peach fuzziness, but these have so much, the peach is white in areas. They're wonderful otherwise, from the farmers' market.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an old tooth-brush it will give better results

Comment: Perfect! I used a new, soft toothbrush. Don't know why these peaches are so very fuzzy, but the toothbrush + a quick rinse in water does the trick!

Answer (score 9):

I've never heard of anyone trying to de-fuzz a peach, so this isn't a direct answer:

It might be simpler to just use nectarines.

It's a myth that it's a cross between a peach and a plum. They are the exact same species, the nectarine is just a peach with the fuzzless recessive genes.

Comment: .and nectarines are soo sweet!

Comment: It may be simpler, but there are different cultivars of peaches. And if I have a peach I love, I may not be able to find a nectarine which tastes the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Simple... drop the freshly picked peaches in cold water in the sink and wash them with clear water and a dishcloth as you would a dish.  It isn't difficult (quick and easy) and you keep all the nutrients that are contained in the skin.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a vegetable brush like you would use to clean dirt off of potatoes.

Answer (score 1):

I use a damp paper towel. Typically I give the peach a rinse in case there are pesticides, then rub them with a paper towel which I compost. It's one of the few things I use paper towels for, but I find it works better than a cloth in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I too like the skin for nutrition and color.  I've found to fill a bucket half full of peaches.  Next turn on your water hose to get that hard fsst spray and wash the fuzz out of them.  It doesn't remove it all but that left is negligiible.  Now you don't have to peel them,  You have a beautiful color for your jam/jelly/cobbler and after boiling and processing, you'll never know they ever had fuzz.  Enjoy...another tip from Jimbo in Mississippi.

Answer (score 1):

Only remove fuzz from peaches you Intend to eat that moment. The fuzz protects the peach and without it they bruise in hours turning the fruit soft and much less appetizing. I use a tooth brush and go gently over the skin. No water needed. So much more appealing then taking a fuzzy bite of fruit.

Answer (score 0):

My mother in law would dip them in hot water with a little calgon in it.

Answer (score -1):

Not heard of it before, but maybe using a cook's blowtorch gently on the skin? Just an idea...

Comment: Interesting idea :-)  Has anyone tried this yet?

Answer (score -1):

Wash the peach. Put it in a bowl.  Pour boiling water from the kettle over it.

Give it a 10 to 20 second soak, and the skin should just peal right off.

Get in the bathtub, and eat under the shower.

Answer (score -1):

A peach and nectarine are the same with the exception of a recessive gene that causes the "peach" to be fuzz free thus making it a NECTARINE!  Buy a nectarine if you want a fuzz free peach!

Comment: hobodave actually already said this, [up above](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4515/1672)! It's still a valid answer, but you'll fare better here if you make new contributions :)

Answer (score -2):

I don't think fuzz removal is common practice...  so you'll have to innovate or steal from another fuzz conscious industry.  My best guess would be a fine-grain sandpaper, or, if it really bothers you, a beard/side-burn trimmer.  They're small, often battery powered, and trim close enough to get facial fuzz, so they should work on peach fuzz too.

Comment: Funny!  Bzzzzz...

Comment: I was actually serious.  What's so crazy about shaving your fruit?

Comment: lol that sounds dirty